# KO - options binding, preselect option from View

Tags: knockout.js

I created a fiddle for demonstration this problem - https://jsfiddle.net/fomigo/9rug9b7c/

ViewModel:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.selected = {
   update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
      allBindingsAccessor().options();
      $(element).val(valueAccessor()).trigger('change');
   }
};


var VM = function(countries, states, cities) {
   var self = this;

   self.countries = ko.observableArray(countries);
   self.states = ko.observableArray(states);
   self.cities = ko.observableArray(cities);

   self.selectedCountry = ko.observable(undefined);
   self.selectedState = ko.observable(undefined);
   self.selectedCity = ko.observable(undefined);

   self.stateOptions = ko.pureComputed(function() {
      return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.states(), function(state) {
         return state.countryId == self.selectedCountry();
      });
   });

   self.cityOptions = ko.pureComputed(function() {
      return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.cities(), function(city) {
         return city.stateId == self.selectedState();
      });
   });
};
```

Model - can be seen in the fiddle.

View:

```
<select data-bind="
   options: countries,
   optionsValue: 'id',
   optionsText: 'name',
   value: selectedCountry,
   selected: 2,
   optionsCaption: 'Choose country...'
"></select>

<select data-bind="
   options: stateOptions,
   optionsValue: 'id',
   optionsText: 'name',
   value: selectedState,
   selected: 7,
   optionsCaption: 'Choose state...'
"></select>

<select data-bind="
   options: cityOptions,
   optionsValue: 'id',
   optionsText: 'name',
   value: selectedCity,
   selected: 14,
   optionsCaption: 'Choose city...'
"></select>
```

There's a need for selecting value in options binding before user actually choose something.
It's going on in the dashboard of a site - there are two state of form, a) for adding item; b) for editing item.
Of course, I want it'd be just one form. So the need for preselecting value after saving item.
And I don't want move my ViewModel to PHP code for setting defaults.

If you change country, the state & cities dropdowns adds strange empty option and caption's hidden.

So, what wrong am I doing?

Thanks.

P.S. Sorry for my English, plz =)

Comment: simple you can set the default values in observable's in viewModel check sample here https://jsfiddle.net/9rug9b7c/11/ . you can avoid binding handler

Comment: yes, that's simple, but I don't want to mix several languages - just simple JS file, without dynamic PHP-chunks of code in it. That's why I want to set the values from View (html, in my case Twig).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be accomplished with a couple of computeds, implementing default selection logic ([updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9rug9b7c/13/)):

```
   ko.computed(function() {
     var firstState = self.stateOptions()[0];
     if(!self.selectedState() && firstState) {
        self.selectedState(firstState.id);
     }
   });
   ko.computed(function() {
     var firstCity = self.cityOptions()[0];
     if(!self.selectedCity() && firstCity) {
         self.selectedCity(firstCity.id);
     }
   });
```

#### Update 1.

If you need just to reset to "Choose someth..." value, you can reset selection to undefined ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9rug9b7c/14/)):

```
   self.stateOptions = ko.pureComputed(function() {
        self.selectedState(undefined);
      return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.states(), function(state) {
         return state.countryId == self.selectedCountry();
      });
   });

   self.cityOptions = ko.pureComputed(function() {
         self.selectedCity(undefined);
      return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.cities(), function(city) {
         return city.stateId == self.selectedState();
      });
   });
```

Comment: Computeds that don't return anything are something of a code smell. `subscribe` is probably the right tool.

Comment: Yes, that's maybe better - but somewhat buggy, I think... It should be displayed 'Choose state...' again, after changing country. But anyway, thank you - it's partially viable solution =)

Comment: @RoyJ - subscribe returns subscription you should dispose after. "computed" also should be disposed. Subscription fires after changes, computed is calculated on creation. As for me - it is 
a matter of taste what to use.

Comment: @RoyJ - It looks like I've got rid of smelling code in update 1 ;)

Comment: @TSV - yes, it's working a little better, but kindly try in Countries' select first USA, then Mexico, then USA. You'll see that there's a subtle bug in this code. I think that a solution is in custom binding "selected", but I'm not sure - it's my first project where I use KnockoutJS.

Comment: @TSV - thanks, your version works perfect now, but - what about requirement to set default values from the View? I mean, now you've set default options from the ViewModel. That's the whole point, - I want preselect values in editing mode from my View, without bothering to change the ViewModel. You see, I've got many more selects on the page - that's I wanted to set values from the View and don't pollute the ViewModel. Maybe I'm wrong, - but just wanted to know how can I do that. Anyway, thanks for all your help! =)

Comment: You can see defaults in the last fiddle -
   self.selectedCountry = ko.observable(2);
   self.selectedState = ko.observable(7);
   self.selectedCity = ko.observable(14);
- you can pass them as function arguments.

Comment: @Igor - BWT, you could accept the answer if it solves your task... ;)

Comment: @TSV - Yes, of course - right now I don't have enough time, but one of these days I want to update my fiddle & accept your answer with the explained solution.